# Sequential http requests inside a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS application I can have different number of http requests to perform sequentially. I think that I need a loop for this purpose:

```
for (let i = 0; i < $scope.entities.length; i++) {
    MyService.createFixedValue($scope.id, $scope.entities[i]);
}
```

where `MyService.createFixedValue` is http POST request:

```
service.createFixedValue = function(property_id, fixed_value_entity){
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/my_url'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: fixed_value_entity
    });
}
```

But in this case my requests are asynchronous. What changes I need to do to get a sequential requests?

Answer (score 4):

### Sequential Requests (Not recommended)

Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) to and [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to create a sequential loop of HTTPRequests.

Build a `async` function like the example below.

```
async function createFixedValues(id, entities) {
  for (const entity of entities) {
    await MyService.createFixedValue(id, entity);
  }
}
```

And call it by injecting the `$scope` properties.

```
createFixedValues($scope.id, $scope.entities);
```

### Single Request and sending an array (recommended)

It will be easier to just send the entire array in a single HTTPRequest instead of sending a request for each *entity*. The result will be the same but a single request will be more efficient.

```
service.createFixedValue = function(property_id, fixed_value_entities) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/my_url'
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: fixed_value_entities
  });
}
```

Give the entire `$scope.entities` array as the second argument.

```
MyService.createFixedValue($scope.id, $scope.entities);
```

You'll have to modify the server side of the request for you are now sending an array instead of a single value. But you have not specified how you handle your server side response, so that is up to you.

Comment: The ES6 promises created by `async`/`await` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To make HTTP requests sequentially, use `$q.all` and `array.reduce`:

```
var sequentialPromise = $scope.entities.reduce( (p, ent)  => {
    var pn = MyService.createFixedValue($scope.id, ent);
    var valuePromise = pn.then(response => response.data);
    var newP = p.then( vArr => {
        return $q.all([...vArr, valuePromise]);
    });
    return newP;
}, $q.when([]) );

sequentialPromise.then(valueArr => {
    console.log(valueArr);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as well as @EmielZuurbier solution! Now I just need to decide which is better for my particular case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try not returning an http POST request. In fact, you may not need to return anything in the function. Just do the post request. If you need to capture the response, push it in a global array.